# large json payload with terraform

Tags: api, rest, terraform

I am using the mastercard rest api provider with terraform and looking for way to put in a large json piece of text in the data field . I tried putting quoes but get

Quoted strings may not be split over multiple lines. To produce a multi-line string, either use the "\n" escape to represent a newline character or use the "heredoc" multi-line template
│ syntax.

How can I clean up this data field?  I saw jsonencode() but I am not too sure.

```
resource "restapi_object" "terraformauto" {
  provider = restapi.restapi_headers
  path = "/api/rest/v1/clusters"
  data = "  {
  "replication_factor": 2,
  "prism_central_configuration": {
    "pc_deployment_config": {
      "pc_spec": {
        "version": "pc.2022.9",
        "capacity_settings": {
          "vm_count": 3
        }
      },
      "network_config": {
        "vpc_cloud_id": "TME-terra-PC",
        "subnet_cloud_id": "Terra-PC",
        "resource_group_name": "tme-terraform-auto",
        "ntp_server_ip_list": [
          "216.239.35.0"
        ],
        "fgw": {
          "ssh_key": {
            "resource_group": "TMEENGKEY",
            "key_name": "multi-tme-eng"
          },
          "number_of_fgw_machines": 1,
          "instance_type": "Standard_D4_v4",
          "ifs": {
            "cloud_id": "Terra-FlowInteral"
          },
          "efs": {
            "cloud_id": "Terra-FlowExternal"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "organization_id": "644d8115-e2f5-4411-b802-d6136c156c2a"
```

tied putting " but no luck

Comment: I prefer to use jsonencode cause then you can paste the real json and if you have an idea it will catch invalid errors in it

Answer (score 0):

Typically the best way to produce JSON in Terraform is to use [Terraform's `jsonencode` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode), because then Terraform is responsible for producing valid JSON syntax and you only need to describe the data structure you want to encode using normal Terraform expressions.

For example:

```
resource "restapi_object" "terraformauto" {
  provider = restapi.restapi_headers
  path     = "/api/rest/v1/clusters"
  data = jsonencode({
    replication_factor = 2
    prism_central_configuration = {
      pc_deployment_config = {
        pc_spec = {
          version = "pc.2022.9"
          capacity_settings = {
            vm_count = 3
          }
        }
        # ...
      }
      # ...
    }
  })
}
```

You can use the table on the `jsonencode` documentation page to learn which data types in Terraform correspond to the different data types in JSON.